# Specify a date-time range with `Calendar` in Android

Tags: java, android, datetime, arraylist, calendar

StackOverflow community,

I' currently working on my new project and I'm new to Java and Android Studio.
I have written my own `Entry` class with two `Calendar` variables.
Is there a shorter and cleaner way to create a new `Entry` object like in the following code?

```
//MainActivity.java    
//....
private ArrayList<Entry> initEntrys() {
        ArrayList<Entry> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        Calendar mStartDate = calendar;
        Calendar mEndDate = calendar;
        mStartDate.set(2019, 12, 20, 7, 0);
        mEndDate.set(2019, 12, 20, 10, 0);
        list.add(new Entry(mStartDate, mEndDate));

        return list;
    }
```

Any help would be really appreciated. :)

Comment: When doing `mStartDate=calendar` and `mEndDate=calendar`, you assign them to the same **reference**. That means, both objects contain the same content, it makes no difference how often you set it.

Comment: @dan1st I just wondered if it isn't possible to make something like `list.add(new Entry(new Calendar(2019, 12, 20, 10, 12, 45), ...))`.

Comment: You can create a helper method that does the work for you.

Comment: Would that be the best way in your opinion or creating a `DateTime` class?

Comment: Don’t create your own date/time class. Use java.time as explained in the answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## tl;dr

Never use the legacy date-time classes such as `Calendar`. **Use only *java.time*** classes.

For a date with time-of-day but lacking a time zone or offset-from-UTC, use [`java.time.LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) class.

```
LocalDateTime.of( 2019 , 12 , 20 , 7 , 0 )  // year, month, day , hour , minute.
```

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

**Never use `Calendar`.** That class is terrible, flawed in its design. It was supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

## *java.time*

In contrast to the legacy classes, the *java.time* classes are immutable by design and therefore thread-safe.

Rather than use constructors with `new`, we instantiate *java.time* objects by calling static factory methods such as [`LocalDateTime.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#of(int,int,int,int,int)).

### Not a moment

If you are consciously working without the context of a [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset), use [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) objects.

```
LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.of( 2019 , 12 , 20 , 7 , 0 ) ;  // Passing year, month, day , hour , minute. The second and fractional-second both default to zero.
LocalDateTime stop = LocalDateTime.of( 2019 , 12 , 20 , 10 , 0 ) ;
```

### Moment

If you are trying to represent moments, specific points on the timeline, then [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) is the *wrong* class.

For tracking moments, you need the context of a time zone (or less preferably, an offset-from-UTC). For that, use [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) as seen in the [Answer by CrackerGen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59506274/642706).

---

[image: Table of all date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

[image: Table of which java.time library to use with which version of Java or Android]

---

Answer (score 3):

I will try to complete [Answer by Basil Bourque](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59506118/642706) by covering a **time zoned** date using the [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) class.

I have used **UTC** time zone in the example but you can customize with the suitable time zone you need.

```
LocalDateTime ldtStart = LocalDateTime.of( 2019 , 12 , 20 , 7 , 0 , 0 , 0 ) ;
ZonedDateTime ldtZonedStart = ldtStart.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
ZonedDateTime utcZonedStart = ldtZonedStart.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);


LocalDateTime ldtStop = LocalDateTime.of( 2019 , 12 , 20 , 10 , 0 , 0 , 0 ) ;
ZonedDateTime ldtStopZoned = ldtStop.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
ZonedDateTime utcZonedStop = ldtStopZoned.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
```